# Cardinality of the power set $\mathcal P\left(S\right),$ where $S$ is a set of $15$ elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, cardinals

What is the cardinality of the power set $\mathcal P\left(S\right)$ where $S$ is a set of $15$ elements?

I think the power set is a set of all the subsets of a given set or $2^n$.  So would the cardinality of this set be $2^{15}$ or $32,768$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *cardinality* of the power set $\mathcal P(S)$ of a set $S$ is given by $2^n$, and so in your case, by $2^{15}$.

Note: There is a difference between a set, and its cardinality. The *power set* $\mathcal P(S)$ itself is the *set* of all subsets of $S$, whereas $2^n$ is the number of these sets (which are the elements) in $\mathcal P(S).$

Comment: Wow you've helped me in every level of my math classes.  From pre-calculus, to integral calculus and linear algebra, to now this class!  As always, thanks for your help!

Comment: You're always welcome, inquisitor.